# Triggering updates / refreshes from outside of AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexeddb

I have a web worker whose job it is to periodically poll a webservice for data, and then insert that data into an IndexedDB database.

Is there any recommended way of notifying an AngularJS module of updates to the object stores, since all the changes happen outside of Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $scope.$apply() when your web worker finishes. You will want to grab the "root" element of where you bootstrapped your ng-app. For example:

HTML:

```
<div id="rootElement" ng-app="myApp">
   ...
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
//Call $apply() to start an angular digest cycle where any updates you made to objects
//angular knows about will update the view.
angular.element(document.getElementById("rootElement")).scope().$apply();
```

**Edit:** Including sample onmessage subscribe.

Since your worker is only writing to the IndexedDb, you will need to also use postMessage to get that data back to your HTML (and angular). For example, in your HTML:

```
var worker = new Worker("pathToWorker.js");
//Start worker in some way
worker.postMessage();

//Use data from the worker to update scope.
worker.addEventListener("message", function (e) {
    //Get the data from the worker
    var indexData = e.data;

    //Update a scope variable (scopevar)
    //Note: The element you query with angular.element must have the scope variable you
    //are interested in.
    angular.element(document.getElementById("MainController")).scope().$apply('scopevar=' + JSON.stringify(indexData));
}, false);
```

From your worker:

```
self.addEventListener("message", function (e) {
    //Do work to write to IndexedDb

    //PostMessage using the indexDb Data so angular can know about it.
    self.postMessage({title: "Foo", data: "Bar"});
}
```

Without seeing your code, I can't give a more specific example, but postMessage from the worker is definitely the way to get data from your worker back to angular.

Comment: But the web worker just write the stuff to IndexedDb. I then need a way of keeping a link between IndexedDb and the controller / scope?

Comment: Call postMessage passing it the data that you are writing to IndexedDb. From your HTML, subscribe to the onmessage in the worker and call $apply() from there with the data... See updated answer.